# How to call a method inside the public static void main(String[] args) class in Java?

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I'm trying to load a json file, convert it into a ConcurrentHashMap and then write into a csv file with the following code:

My json file is of the form

{"lemmas":{"doc4":"which might make it go wrong","doc3":"and no dirty datum","doc2":"each of vary length","doc1":"you should find that it have five line","doc0":"this be a simple text file"}}

```
    package pipeline;
    
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Map.Entry;
    import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
    
    import helpers.JSONIOHelper;
    
    public class DescriptiveStatistics {
    
        private static void StartCreatingStatistics(String filePath) {
            System.out.println("Loading file...");
    
            JSONIOHelper JSONIO = new JSONIOHelper(); // create an object of the JSONIOHelper class
            JSONIO.LoadJSON(filePath); // call the LoadJSON method
            ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> lemmas = JSONIO.GetLemmasFromJSONStructure();
            
    
            lemmas.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("    %s%n", v));
    
            CountWordsInCorpus(lemmas); // call this method from the end of the StartCreatingStatistics()
        }
    
        private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> CountWordsInCorpus(ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> lemmas) {
    
            // compile the words in the corpus into a list
            ArrayList<String> corpus = new ArrayList<String>();
            // store the words together with their frequencies
            ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> counts = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();
        
            for (Entry<String, String> entry : lemmas.entrySet()) {
    
                for (String word : entry.getValue().split(" ")) {
    
                    corpus.add(word);
    
                }
            }

   // getting words and their frequencies 
            for (String word : corpus) {
                if (counts.containsKey(word)) {
                    counts.put(word, counts.get(word) + 1);
                } else {
                    counts.put(word, 1);
    
                }
            
            }
                                
            return counts;
        }
    // writing into a csv file
        private void OutputCountsAsCSV(ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> counts, String filename) {
            String CSVOutput = new String("");
    
            for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : counts.entrySet()) {
                String rowText = String.format("%s,%d\n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    
                System.out.println(rowText);
                CSVOutput += rowText;
                System.out.println(CSVOutput);
    
                {
                    try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename)) {
                        writer.write(CSVOutput);
                        System.out.println("CSV File saved successfully...");
                    }
    
                    catch (Exception e)
    
                    {
                        System.out.println("Saving CSV to file failed...");
    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I now want to call the OutputCountsAsCSV() method to pass the csv file name to it, say 'my_file.csv'.

I am not sure how to do it in the main(String[] args) method.
It is easy to call StartCreatingStatistics(), for example, because there is only one argument, but OutputCountsAsCSV() has two arguments and I do not know how to pass ‘counts’ from ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> CountWordsInCorpus() to it as the first argument?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String filePath = "JSON_simple.json";       
    DescriptiveStatistics newobj = new 
DescriptiveStatistics();
    newobj.StartCreatingStatistics(filePath);
    ...
    // ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> newhashmap = 
//newobj.CountWordsInCorpus()
    String filename = "my_file.csv";      
    OutputCountsAsCSV ( newhashmap, filename);
}
```

So if I try 'ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> newhashmap = newobj.CountWordsInCorpus()'; it of course, gives an error  'the method CountWordsInCorpus(ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>)' in the type BDescriptiveStatistics is not applicable for the arguments()'.

how can I do it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> newhashmap = newobj.CountWordsInCorpus()`

This line is fine; but it back. Except, the `CountWordsInCorpus` method has an argument: lemmas. You need to find these lemmas someplace and pass them to this method. Your `StartCreatingStatistics` method does this, but it calls `CountWordsInCorpus`, and tosses the result in the garbage.

Perhaps `StartCreatingStatistics` should return it instead. Now your main can call `StartCreatingStatistics`, save what it returns, and pass that to `OutputCountsAsCSV`.

Comment: I have changed to private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> StartCreatingStatistics(String filePath)  and added return CountWordsInCorpus(lemmas);   yet, OutputCountsAsCSV (newobj.StartCreatingStatistics(filePath), filename); does not work.

Comment: wait a sec. I have also changed to private static void OutputCountsAsCSV() and it worked!  thank you very much.